# Java file zip is creating corrupt files

Tags: java, zip

I am attempting to zip files from one folder into a zip folder located in another directory. The problem is that the zip folder is becoming corrupted. What is causing this and how do I fix it.

```
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/admin/Documents/files.zip");
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
        File folder = new File("C:/Users/admin/Documents/filestozip");

        for(File file:folder.listFiles())
        {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(file.getAbsolutePath());
            zos.putNextEntry(entry);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int length;

            while((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0)
            {
                zos.write(bytes, 0, length);
            }

            zos.closeEntry();
            fis.close();
        }

        zos.flush();
        zos.finish();
        zos.close();
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
```

Comment: What makes you think it is corrupt?

Comment: I'm just following suit of the other questions I saw regarding this. Maybe my terminology is wrong. The zip file is empty when I open it using Windows Explorer and when i attempt to extract the contents a message appears stating "Windows cannot complete the extraction. The compressed (zipped) folder (path) is invalid."

Comment: Well you have `C://Users`, which should be `C:/Users`, twice, and which is indeed invalid from Windows' point of view.

Comment: @Y2i There is no `ZipEntry.close()` method, and [`ZipOutputStream.putNextEntry()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html#putNextEntry-java.util.zip.ZipEntry-) 'closes the current entry if still active'.

Comment: Change the path as as suggessted and added in the zos.closeEntry(). Still nothing. See the updated code

Comment: It's possible that `entry = new ZipEntry(file.getAbsolutePath());` is causing you some trouble. Can you try it with the relative path name?

Comment: Which would be a better idea anyway. You don't want the entire path including the drive and root directory in the ZIP file, otherwise you can't unzip it anywhere else. @dave

Comment: Oh brother, it was the relative path after all! Thanks @dave and EJP for your help. One last thing, I'm planning on using this code in my web application running on the Glassfish server. Do you know if using the "../" in my file path cause any issues? Like for the zip entry

Comment: @Stephan Are you sure you didn't get an exception while writing the file? For example you aren't ignoring directories in your outer loop. Your code works for me, with that change, but it doesn't show the internal files unless I use `File.getName()` instead of `File.getAbsolutePath()` or `File.getPath()` when constructing the `ZipEntry`.

Comment: I would avoid `..`. Your copy loop should be `> 0`, as `read()` can only return zero if the buffer is zero length, and this is not a condition you want to loop forever on.

Comment: The compiler was awfully quiet during this process sadly. The `getAbsolutePath()` method returned the entire path for me inclusive of the name of the file. The `getName()` method would only return the name of the file.

Comment: That's what you want. You want the liberty to unzip it somewhere else. If you put the entire path in there, that's the only place it can be unzipped to.